# how to generate binary vector from multi class labels having same x value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example

```
train = pd.DataFrame({"letter":["hem", "hem", "hem", "kiran","kiran"], "val": ['A','B','C','A','B']})
train

letter  val
hem     A
hem     B
hem     C
kiran   A
kiran   B


train=pd.concat([train,pd.get_dummies(train['val'])], axis=1)

letter  val A   B   C
hem     A   1   0   0
hem     B   0   1   0
hem     C   0   0   1
kiran   A   1   0   0
kiran   B   0   1   0
```

but how to generate vector from unique letter
that means based on y column it creates dummy vales for each y value so
my query is how to create vector for each x value based on y

like below table i want?

```
letter      A   B   C
hem         1   1   1
kiran       1   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a the below code at the end of the code:

```
print(train.groupby('letter', as_index=False).sum())
```